# How to handle multiple activities with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to implement an app through fragments.

Based on my requirements,i have a menu panel one side and other side i need to display different ui screens based on menu selection.

My Screen contains heavy ui.That why i design each screen separately.

How should i display screens based on menu selections through fragments.

If any one know the solution,Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to find on google? Because there are many samples available on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the NavigationDrawer you find the official [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on the Android Developers Website

There is also an example to download, which uses the NavigationDrawer to switch Fragments.

If you want a fixed, self-designed Menu and just want to swap out Fragments (holded by a FrameLayout) check out this [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android officially doesn't provide more than one sliding menus (navigation drawers). You can implement [SlideMenu](https://github.com/TangKe/SlideMenu) or choose one of many such libraries for more than one sliding menus. 

Once the menus are implemented, it's just a simple case of fragments and activities. There is no "direct way". Read the documentation and understand how they work. Here are some good links

[Fragments - Introduction on developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[Tutorial on multi-pane development using fragments by Mr. Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Basically what you have to do is, create an Activity extending `ActionBarActivity` (from support library) or `FragmentActivity`.
create fragments and replace them in `FragmentManager` from your main activity.

See this for reference:

[Creating a navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)